# Angular variable not defined inside my service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a problem with my angular code and I can't figure out where's it's from.

I want to return the result json of my api call, I DONT want a promise or anything I want the json result of the $http service.

When i'm outside of the $http my variable result is set to *'undefined'* but inside the $http service it's set to the result of the json.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory("Content", function ContentFactory($http) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            var result;
            $http.get('wp-json/acf/post/2').success(function(res){
                result = res.acf;
                console.log(result); // 'Object'
            });
            console.log(result); // 'undefined'
            return result;
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Use promises, they are really convenient here. You *could* return from your service, but it's not recommended.

Comment: so we must use promises what ever happens ;) it didn't know that async calls fork in another process.

Comment: You don't have to use Promises, but it's the simplest, cleaner and effective solution in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/p3aj577u/

Comment: Okey, thank you very much :)